# Открыть изображение в стандартном менеджере обоев

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Прошел пол интернета в поиске ответа, которого пока не нашел.

Есть приложение с обоями на рабочий стол, которое использует стандартный метод `WallpaperManager.setBitmap()`.

Но как сделать чтобы выбранное изображение открылось в стандартном системном приложении выбора обоев?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел на просторах интернета

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                    emailIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileForImage), "image/*");
                    //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileForImage));
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
```